# Could pointer_traits typedefs be undefined?

Tags: c++, stl

I get stucked on the way of writing my own implementation of STL. The question occurred when I tried to implement std::pointer_traits. By default, std::pointer_traits evaluate his typedef's based on the passed parameter, like follow:

```
template <typename Ptr>
struct pointer_traits
{
    typedef typename Ptr::element_type  element_type;
    ...
};
```

But here is where the standard says that poiter_traits are ill-formed. When Ptr has no predefined typedef element_type and so on, the compiled error is guaranteed. My implementation offers a new approach. Whenever we try to evaluate typedef's, we will choose between two options:

1. When Ptr has desired typedef's, we take they as well
2. When Ptr has not targed typedef's, we will define them as undefined (std::__undefined)

Functions and other stuff are intentionally omitted for simplicity

```
template <typename Ptr>
class pointer_traits
{
private:
    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct __ptr 
    {
        typedef __undefined         ptr;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct __ptr<T, vstl::__void_t<typename T::pointer*>>
    {
        typedef typename T::pointer ptr;
    };

    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct __eltype
    {
        typedef __undefined             element_type;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct __eltype<T, vstl::__void_t<typename T::element_type*>>
    {
        typedef typename T::element_type element_type;
    };

    template <typename T, typename = void>
    struct __difftype
    {
        typedef std::ptrdiff_t          difference_type;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct __difftype<T, vstl::__void_t<typename T::difference_type*>>
    {
        typedef typename T::difference_type difference_type;
    };

public:
    using pointer = typename __ptr<Ptr>::ptr;
    using element_type = typename __eltype<Ptr>::element_type;
    using difference_type = typename __difftype<Ptr>::difference_type;
};
```

This approach will increase pointer_traits stability, but may lead to a misunderstanding. When a type does not provide desired functionality, why we should even instantiate a pointer_traits??? And at a single moment, the state of pointer_traits instance will be undefined for itself. Some members will be defined, some will not.

**Does my implementation make sense?**

Comment: SFINAE techniques rely on constructs being ill-formed.  It's more SFINAE-friendly for, say, `pointer_traits<int>::element_type` to be ill-formed than for it to be a typedef for some special sentinel type. This is why the standard tends to require that things that don't make sense are not present at all.

Comment: That approach relies on the user decision about type, if the type were not be defined, then he can make a decision on his own